# Toshiba Satellite C655 blinking power LED, refusing to turn on

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-repair

One minute the laptop works fine, the next it refuses to turn on. The only clue given as to why this is happening is a blinking power LED.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the battery and removing one ram module. Neither method worked.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do given your tests is to get it serviced at a local shop.

Comment: But the computer itself is 8 years old so I doubt they can fix that sort of thing. I’m not so sure though.

Comment: It may be time to replace the computer.

Comment: They're the ones best able to tell whether or not they can fix such an issue.